# How do you install openLayers 3 locally?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am new to OpenLayers and I have to develop an offline application that uses it.  I have downloaded OL 3.7.0 and set it up with a test html file that loads the OL javascript file via:

```
<script src="./build/ol.js"></script>
```

The next thing I do is get the version via:

```
document.write(ol.VERSION_NUMBER);
```

My questions are:

1. Is "VERSION_NUMBER" only an openLayers 2 property?  How do I verify the version of ol that I am running?
2. Did I install ol3 properly or do I need to do something else?  I can't seem to find anything that talks about how to install ol3

Comment: If by "offline application" you mean an HTML page running on a machine with no Internet access then don't "install" any JS libraries; as long as you the browser can reach the specified URLs you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes VERSION_NUMBER doesn't exist in ol3, the version number of ol3 you use is written on top of the `ol.js` file.

2) ol3 is pure javascript so, if you load  the compiled file (ol.js) in your HTML page, you don't need more to use it. If you want to compile yourself the library, have a look to [the github page](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3)